# Does boost asio ssl::stream<tcp::socket> supports multiple pending http::async_write calls?

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, asio, beast

I have a http client that performs http::async_write() with a callback that performs http::async_read() on ssl::stream. All the async operations are wrapped in the same explicit strand.

The simplified code looks like this

```
http::async_write(
        *tcp_session_->tcp_stream(), *request,
        boost::asio::bind_executor(
            tcp_session_strand_,
            [request, this](
                boost::system::error_code ec,
                std::size_t /* bytes_transferred */) {
              if (ec) {
                return;
              }
              auto response_buffer =
                  std::make_shared<boost::beast::flat_buffer>();
              auto response = std::make_shared<HttpResponse>();
              http::async_read(
                  *tcp_session_->tcp_stream(), *response_buffer, *response,
                  boost::asio::bind_executor(
                      tcp_session_strand_,
                      [request, done, response_buffer, response](
                          boost::system::error_code ec,
                          std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
                        if (ec) {
                          // log error
                          return;
                        }
                      }));
            }));
```

I call the async_write like this two times in a row. I don't wait for the first async_write handler completion before the second write is performed.

The behavior that I see is. The first async_write is completed, then the second async_write is completed, then the first async_read is invoked with the error: "Operation canceled". This reproduces quite consistently, so I assume ssl::stream does not support multiple pending http requests. Basically one has to wait for the response before sending next request.

Is my assumption correct? I read the documentation for ssl::stream but it does not say anything about that (only that async operations have to be serialized by strand).

Answer (score 1):

Per [Beast documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__http__async_write/overload1.html) for async_write:

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_write_some function, and is known as a composed operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other writes until this operation completes.